# FOPEN not accepting directory path

Tags: oracle, csv

I'm having trouble with the line

```
F := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('my_directory', 'MyCSV.csv', 'R');
```

After previously running

```
CREATE DIRECTORY my_directory AS 'C:\Users\timfo\eclipse-workspace\CSVCreation';
```

which succeeds. The error I'm getting is

```
ORA-29280: invalid directory path
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 41
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 478
ORA-06512: at line 9
29280. 00000 -  "invalid directory path"
*Cause:    A corresponding directory object does not exist.
*Action:   Correct the directory object parameter, or create a corresponding
       directory object with the CREATE DIRECTORY command.
```

but I've made sure that the user has permission with

```
grant create any directory to TimGraupner2;

CREATE DIRECTORY my_directory AS 'C:\Users\timfo\eclipse-workspace\CSVCreation';

grant read on directory my_directory to TimGraupner2;
```

and all those succeeded. I've tried entering the full directory path in the FOPEN line, and that didn't work either. What's going on?

Comment: If you check the docs, in the fine print they mention that the directory name has to be in upper case. So `UTL_FILE.FOPEN('MY_DIRECTORY', ...`

Comment: @kfinity that's quite possible the most annoying error I've ever had. Thank you!!!!

Comment: @TimGraupner - unless quoted, all names in Oracle are converted to upper case when stored in the system tables. So if you wanted to refer to your directory as `'my_directory`' (in lower case) you'd have to quote it when creating it, e.g. `CREATE DIRECTORY "my_directory" AS ...`. Note that you could (potentially) have directories `'MY_DIRECTORY'`, `'my_directory'`, `'My_Directory'`, `'My_directory'`, and `'My_DiReCtOrY'` if for some reason you wanted them. :-)